# Why my unordered lists are floating to the right instead of left?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new at coding and I've started to make some unordered lists but it seems that starting from the 3rd `ul` they keep floating to the right instead of left. What is wrong with my code?

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    <title>resume</title>
</head>

<body>

                <p id="name"> my name </p>

        <a href="mailto:myemailaddress@gmail.com"><p id="email">myemailaddress@gmail.com</p></a>

        <div class="left"></div>

        <div class="right">

        <header>
        <h4>Objective</h4>
        </header>

        <p>Some words here.</p>

        <h4>objectives</h4>

        <ul>
            <li> some content here some content here</li>
            <li> some content here some content here</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li> some content here some content here</li>
            <li> some content here some content here </li>
        <ul>
        <br/>

        <ul>
            <li>some content here some content here</li>
            <li>some content here some content here</li>
        <ul>
        </br>

        <ul>
            <li>some content here some content here</li>
            <li>some content here some content here</li>
        <ul>
        </br>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the CSS file:

```
.left {
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 10%;
height: 1000px;
background-color: #B9D7D9;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.right {
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 88%;
height: 1000px;
background-color: #F4EBC3;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you add some screenshot explaining your issue??

Comment: its perfectly working, all ul bullets float left

Comment: Are you trying to make a single list? If so, you should have a single `ul`element with several `li` elements inside. Also, is this a complete example? It looked fine when I tried.

Comment: Hi @Pugazh, I have edited my question, copy and pasted the exact same html file I have plus I included a screenshot. The problem is first two `ul` elements are floating to the left but 3rd and 4th `ul` elements are floating to the right. when I add more `ul` or <p> with content they keep floating to the right.

Comment: Hello @Djizeus, There are 4 `ul` elements. I have edited my question and I hope it's much more clear. I have included a screenshot as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a text editor that helps you validate the syntax of your HTML (for example with tag auto-closing or syntax error highlighting). The problem is that out of the 4 lists, 3 have a wrong closing tag: it should be `</ul>` instead of `<ul>`.

Moreover, in XML a self-closing tag has the slash at the end of the tag, not the beginning. So the newlines should be written `<br/>`.

If you fix these two problems, the lists will be displayed as you expect.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I've missed them. I've fixed them and they're all displayed as expected. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @SabaSbt If your issue is fixed, please accept the answer and optionnally upvote it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we have to structure the HTML correctly.

What you have initially, is not one list but 4 lists all containing a single list item.

So we tidy that up and it all works fine.

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #B9D7D9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 88%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #F4EBC3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>

<div class="right">

  <ul>
    <li>Some Link</li>
    <li>Some Link</li>
    <li>Some Link</li>
    <li>Some Link</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello @paulie_D , thank you for taking the time to answer my question :)  as my html code was incomplete and not so clear I have edited it and added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should consider that if you want to use bullet lists you should write your code like:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
  </ul>
```

There can also be the problem of your containing `<div>` if the size is smaller than the content it can cause some issues.

the code you wrote just floats the `<div>` tags if you want to align your list items to left or write use this code:

```
ul li{
    float:right;
  }
```

You can also check links below for more info:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/08.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

Comment: Hi @Explosion , thank you for the solution and links :) I tried them still floating to the right problem is still there. as my question was incomplete and unclear I have edited it and added a screenshot.